How can i make storms (clouds) like in Twisted or Helicity?
I'm working on a storm system in Roblox Studio and trying to replicate the layered storm effects seen in games like Twisted or Helicity. I want to use weld parts to create layers for rain (light rain, heavy rain, hail, etc.), and also include a mesocyclone. How would you suggest setting up the welded parts for these storm layers and mesocyclone, and do you have any advice for scripting generation in such a system?
I haven't started implementing anything yet because I'm unsure where to begin with creating the storm system using weld parts. I’m looking for guidance on how to approach setting up the layers and scripting the tornado generation. Any tips or examples would be really helpful!

You may want to check the [tour] and [ask].
